# Laravel Auth Does not redirect back after incorrect login/registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the default Laravel 5.8 authentication model. It worked fine, but recently I noticed that after I enter the wrong credentials in the login form, it still redirects me to the homepage, and in the corner the browser asks me if I want to save password and etc. Everything looks like I was logged in, but I'm not.

If I enter the correct information, then I get logged in and everything works fine.

I was looking for a solution, but everything I could find was modifying LoginController and RegisterController, and I think I don't want to do that, because default behavior is what I need. So the problem must be somewhere else.

I don't know what code to show. My best guess of what could be related is:

web.php

```php
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

app/Http/Kernel.php middleware groups

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\Administrator::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

What I expect: to be redirected back to the same page after an incorrect login/registration.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I had this

```
<meta name=“referrer" content=“origin”>
```

in my html